# Get Grand Total of Fields in iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a *jTable* with two columns as **Outflows** and **Amount**.
I used iReport and print the things in the *jTable* without errors. Now I want to get the total of **Amount** Field.

I tried it in many ways. It shows casting problem. I know the place which gives the error. It is the Field name I created to import *jTable's* **Amount** details (I created it as COLUMN_1 & Field Class is String) Here I used Field Class as String because if I used Integer it gives this error :-

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :   Source text : $F{COLUMN_1}
```

But the problem is that. That should be Integer. Otherwise we can't do calculations from that Field. If I put it Integer the above error occur as.Here is my report viewing code

```
try {
        JRTableModelDataSource datasource = new JRTableModelDataSource(jt.getModel());
        String report = url;
        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("rep_title",jLabel1.getText());
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params, datasource);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Please do something for my error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have different class definition on field and variable.

If we consider that the `$F{COLUMN_1}` is `java.lang.Integer` this would be the correct way

Within your `subDataset` that you pass to the table define the field and variable

```
<field name="COLUMN_1" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>

<variable name="TOTAL" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
  <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLUMN_1}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

**NOTE: same class** `java.lang.Integer`

Then add the variable `$V{TOTAL}` as textfield where you like it to be I guess in the `jr:columnFooter`

```
<textField>
  <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="41" uuid="2c37dd10-91c4-4502-b6b0-5d09268153fa"/>
 <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{TOTAL}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Be sure to not add any String function to the `$V{TOTAL}` in the `textfield` es `$V{TOTAL}.indexOf(...)` will not work you need to first get the String object es. `$V{TOTAL}.toString().indexOf` will work

Comment: If I used Integer for COLUMN_1 it gives an error.. that's should be corrected.. problem is that, how to correct that..

Comment: Check all class definitions, post your relevant jrxml and I will check